# Angular Error: [$injector:unpr] using controller / factory setup with asp.net (SinglePage Application)

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, rest, single-page-application

I am trying to get used to develop Angular in a SPA application, and have encountered an error i just cannot seem to get my head around..

The error is :

Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$injector/unpr?     p0=dataFactoryProvider%20%3C-%20dataFactory
    at Error (native)
    at bla-bla-bla/Scripts/angular.min.js:6:450
    at bla-bla-bla/Scripts/angular.min.js:35:431
    at Object.c [as get] (hbla-bla-bla/Scripts/angular.min.js:34:13)
    at bla-bla-bla/Scripts/angular.min.js:35:499
    at c (bla-bla-bla/Scripts/angular.min.js:34:13)
    at d (bla-bla-bla/Scripts/angular.min.js:34:230)
    at Object.instantiate (bla-bla-bla/Scripts/angular.min.js:34:394)
    at $get (bla-bla-bla/Scripts/angular.min.js:66:112)
    at bla-bla-bla/Scripts/angular.min.js:53:14

It's a controller using a Factory communicating with REST-services on the back-end. (asp.net)

Here is the controller (loginscripts.js - nevermind the login-stuff.. it's just for testing)

```
var photoAppLogin = angular.module('photoAppLogin', ['ngRoute']);

// bla-bla- routing stuff..

photoAppLogin.controller('mainController', ['$scope', 'dataFactory',
function ($scope, dataFactory) {

    $scope.loggedInUser;
    $scope.status;

// create a message to display in our view
$scope.message = 'Loginform here !';

$scope.LoginUser = function () {
    var uname = $scope.Username;
    var pw = $scope.Pass;

    dataFactory.getUser(uname, pw)
        .success(function(usr) {
            $scope.loggedInUser = usr;
            $.cookie('loggedInUser', uname);
        })
        .error(function(error) {
        $scope.status = "User not found" + error.message;
    });
}
}]);
```

Here is the code for the Factory :

```
angular.module('photoAppLogin').factory('dataFactory', ['$http', function ($http) {
var urlBase = 'Pages/loginform.html';
var dataFactory = {};

dataFactory.getUser = function (username, password) {
    return $http.get(urlBase, username, password);
};

return dataFactory;
}]);
```

Here is the Rest-services (asp.net class)

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string username, string password)
        {
            var authUser = ControllerBasePage.UserServices.AuthenticateUser(username, password);
        if (authUser != null)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, authUser);
        }
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }
```

What am i missing here ? This should be pretty straight forward, but i cannot seem to figure out this, OR... to debug this in a proper way to find the actual error :)

Hope you can assist me with this !

Comment: Everything you have shown seems ok, so I am guessing you are not loading your js files correctly. Try create a simpler version (say in a single file, and work from there).

Comment: good point !.. that was not in my mind :) post a comment on it incase this solves it will you ?

Comment: Hmm.. still stuck with this, either though the html file has the js'es loaded this order :

    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Factories/dataFactory.js"></script>
    <script src="loginscripts.js"></script>